# How to create a trigger programmatically for an open event in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, triggers

I'm playing around with Google Apps script and encountering a weird error when trying to programmatically create a trigger (not bound to a specific file or anything).

I am trying to run a certain code - basically to edit a document in Google Docs whenever it opens, but I'm experiencing this error:

> Unexpected error while getting the method or property create on object
>   ScriptApp.DocumentTriggerBuilder. (line 9, file "Code")DetailsDismiss

Here's the code that I'm using:

```
 /**
 * Creates a trigger for when a spreadsheet opens.
 */
function createSpreadsheetOpenTrigger() {
  var d = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
        .forDocument(d)
        .onOpen()
        .create();
}


function myFunction() {
     // change the body or something...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getActiveDocument won’t work if the script isn’t bound to a document. You want openById.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that, but I'm trying to apply this to all documents, so basically all documents onOpen event. Basically: whenever any document is opened, I add something to the end of it or something...

Comment: Oops! I didn't mean to post this as an answer. You can't have something `onOpen` for EVERY document. You have to explicitly add an `onOpen` trigger to a document.

Comment: Oh, thanks for clarifying with that. By the way, I wouldn't have gotten this without your answer, so all's good!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to create a trigger on open? `onOpen` is a trigger itself.

Try this

```
function onOpen(e)
{
    myFunction();
}
```

Comment: Yes that's true, but I believe that's only done in the situation where it's bound to a container, or a file. For example, you could have that in an apps script and it'd only trigger/execute on the file you bound it to. But I'm trying to do this across all documents/spreadsheets/containers...